# How to remove CustomListViewItem

Tags: android, android-layout

Hy !

My Code:

i just want to remove a item in a listview. But that code doesn't work for me.

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, final View arg1,
                    final int arg2, long arg3) {
                final Pizza pizza = (Pizza)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you to delete " + pizza.title + "?")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              // ListView lv2 = (ListView)arg1;
                               arg0.removeView(arg0.getChildAt(arg2));
                                arg0.removeViewAt(arg2);
                                    myDB = Main.this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                                    myDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM+"+MY_DB_TABLE+ "WHERE ID="+pizza.id);

                           }
                       })
                       ;
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Error:

```
10-03 08:25:12.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(391): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeViewAt(int) is not supported in AdapterView
```

Comment: if you are using array list in adapter class then update your array list and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you must have a call to the ListView Adapter

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i have i customadapter i called the notifyDataSetChanged() method but the error occures again